# Booting to recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, bootloader, sony-xperia-mini-pro

I have Xperia mini pro (4.1.B.0.587 Stock ram), and my bootloader is unlocked.
But I could not boot to recovery mode by pulsing volume down button. I press it after phnoe shakes and before displaying "SONY".

What is wrong?

Update: Whene I install stock ROMs (using .ftf) files The recovery mode is wiped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear whether you had flashed CWM's recovery (through boot image). If you had done, you have to press vol up and down while powering on. If not, you do not have a recovery mode at all. You have to flash it using fastboot as described in CyanogenMod's [How to install CM in Sony Xperia Mini Pro](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_mango).

Comment: I previously was installed CyanogenMod for a while, and replaced it with Stock ROMs (4.1.B.0.587)

Comment: Indeed I want install http://www.technikan.com/how-to-update-sony-xperia-mini-pro-sk17isk17a-to-android-4-1-2-paranoid-custom-rom/ on my phone. Should I yet follow CM related steps?

Comment: Yep. Follow till 10th point in section **Installing CyanogenMod on Sony Devices** and in the 10th point choose the zip file for "Paranoidandroid Jelly Bean 4.1.2".

Answer (score 0):

I think You 1st Press volume button then power it up keep pressing voulme button untill it shakes.. In My Galaxy Gio I do this for bootinh to recovery mode.

Comment: I tried it, no success.