# Sony Xperia Z stuck in a bootloop

Tags: recovery-mode, boot-loop, sony-xperia-z

My Xperia Z is stuck int a bootloop. It goes up to the colorful waves and then it restarts. It was connected with USB in charging mode. Suddenly, it starts restarting. I thought it might be carrying out some of its processes, but even after an hour of restarts, it failed to start normally. Now my battery is completely drained.

I want to recover/restore it to factory settings, but I can't because of bootloops.

The phone is only two months old, and I do not want to format and restore flash files
via flashtools as suggested on the XDA forums. Getting into recovery mode and restoring from there will be preferred, instead of flashing. My last resort will be a Sony Service Center.

Comment: You might want to check [Booting to recovery](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42822/16575), which is about a Xperia mini pro (being a Sony Xperia device lets me hope it fits). If you can boot into recovery, you should be able to do a factory reset from there.

Comment: I fixed the boot loop for Sony XZ1 by following this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/XLgKW_8sF8Q) using Xperia Companion

Answer (score 2):

You have to download a rom for your mobile.

Download it from

https://xperiastockrom.com/category/firmware

Download a flashtool from

https://developer.sony.com/develop/open-devices/get-started/flash-tool/

1. open the  flashtool
2. Connect a USB cable to your computer.
3. Turn off your phone.
4. Connect your phone to the USB cable while holding the Volume down key.
5. Select the software you want to flash in the Service list. The tool automatically detects the phone model and lists available software versions.
6. Click on Apply Service. The phone will now be flashed.
7. When you have flashed your device, you can disconnect your phone from the computer. The first time the boot-up might take a little longer than normal.

Hope it will solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

Download the flash tool and search for "FTF stock images". Find your phone's model number and download at least 4 different versions of the stock Firmware from beginning to newest. Flash following instructions. This will fix this!

Comment: It would be better if you could explain more in detail, though...

Answer (score 0):

You can install a fresh and latest rom by these steps:

1. Download and install latest [Flashtool](http://www.flashtool.net/downloads.php).
2. Then check your phone exact model (For xperia z: C6602,C6603,c6606,...).
3. You should download the latest firmware for your model from valid sources like XDA. In any topic you find, there should be a "How to" that you can easily follow.
4. Wiping data folder will delete all your settings, apps, phone numbers, ... (Don't forget to backup!)

Useful **note**: [Flash FTF using flashtool](https://www.google.com/search?q=c6606&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b#q=flash%20ftf%20using%20flashtool)

Answer (score 0):

Since google favors this thread, I will follow up with what worked for me: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/need-help-flashing-xz2-ftf-flash-fails.3873024/post-78287147

That post states:

> (Newflasher thread is here:
> https://forum.xda-developers.com/cr...gress-newflasher-xperia-command-line-t3619426
> and the version I used was the latest (v13))
>
> Simple steps for using newflasher instead of FlashTool:
>
> - Use Xperifirm to download appropriate firmware for your device    Firmware auto-unpacks to
>   C:\users\yourusername.flashtool\firmwares\downloads\xxx
> - Remove any    .ta files you may not want to flash (The only one I know to remove is    simlock.ta , as I don't want to risk
>   re-sim-locking my device)
> - Copy    the newflasher.exe to the folder that contains the unpacked firmware    (example would be folder xxx above)
> - Don't run newflasher.exe yet
> - Get    your phone into Flashmode (for this XZ2 it is to have the phone    powered off, then hold the VOLDOWN button while plugging the
>   USB    cable in)

The resources mentioned in the other answers makes it difficult to find images for newer xperias. Apparently the newflash tool's distribution goes through the xda-developers forum. Same goes for the [firmware development tool](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tool-xperifirm-xperia-firmware-downloader-v5-6-5.2834142/).